# Relationship to a third model through a pivot table in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent-relationship

I am a beginner to Laravel and I have the following schema I'm playing with:

```
Course {
  id,
  name,
  teacher_id
}

Category {
  id,
  name
}

Teacher {
  id,
  name
}

CategoryCourses {
  id,
  course_id,
  category_id
}
```

As you can see, CategoryCourses is my pivot table and I'm using `belongsToMany` between Courses & Category.

Now - what do I want to do? I'm trying to create a `show` view for Category where I click on the Category and it should display all the Courses with that category AND the Teacher whose teaching that respective Course.

So for example - if I have 4 Laravel courses that have the "Web Development" category - I want to display all of them on a card, with the Teacher's name on each of them.

Following are my models:

**Category**

```
class Category extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name'
    ];

    public function courses()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Course::class, 'course_categories', 'course_id', 'category_id');
    }

    public function teacher()
    {
        return $this->hasOneThrough(Teacher::class, CourseCategory::class);
    }
    
}
```

**Course**:

```
    class Course extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name','description','cover','difficulty', 'teacher_id'
    ];

    public function teachers() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Teacher::class, 'teacher_id', 'id');
    }

    public function categories() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'course_categories');
    }
}
```

**Teacher**:

```
class Teacher extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name','email','password', 'avatar'
    ];

   public function courses() {
       return $this->hasMany('Course', 'teacher_id');
   }

}
```

**CategoryController - show($id)**:

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $category = Category::findOrFail($id)->first();

        
        $course = Category::with('courses','teacher')->get();
        return view('admin.showcoursesbycategory', compact('category', 'course'));
    }
```

This is the error I'm getting after writing the `$course = Category::with('teacher')` code:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'teachers.course_category_id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `teachers`.*, `course_categories`.`category_id` as `laravel_through_key` from `teachers` inner join `course_categories` on `course_categories`.`id` = `teachers`.`course_category_id` where `course_categories`.`category_id` in (1, 2, 3, 4))
```

How do I achieve what I'm trying to do? What am I doing wrong? Kindly help me out here.

Comment: `teacher` would be a relationship to `Course`, and shouldn't have anything to do with Category. Code would probably be `Category::with('courses.teacher') ...`, which would load all the Corses for the Category, and the Teacher (single) for each Course.

Comment: So I have shifted teacher() to Course and changed the with() expression, but when I dd() it - the "courses" are coming up empty. And they shouldn't. And it's not even loading the teacher relation in the dd() relations.

```public function show($id)
    {
        
        $categories = Category::where('id',$id)->with('courses.teacher')->get();
        return view('admin.showcoursesbycategory', compact('categories'));
    }``` <- Here's my show() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that each course has only one teacher, following normal naming conventions the relationship should be named as `teacher` on the `Course` model

```php
class Course extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name','description','cover','difficulty', 'teacher_id'
    ];

    public function teacher() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Teacher::class, 'teacher_id', 'id');
    }

    public function categories() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'course_categories', 'course_id', 'category_id');
    }
}
```

I guess you need to fix the relationship signature in **Category** model

```php
class Category extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name'
    ];

    public function courses()
    {
        /**
         * Change
         * return $this->belongsToMany(Course::class, 'course_categories', 'course_id', 'category_id');
         */
        return $this->belongsToMany(Course::class, 'course_categories', 'category_id', 'course_id');
    }

    public function teacher()
    {
        return $this->hasOneThrough(Teacher::class, CourseCategory::class);
    }
    
}
```

Then in the controller you can write the query as

```php
public function show($id)
{
    $category = Category::with('courses.teacher')->findOrFail($id);


    return view('admin.showcoursesbycategory', compact('category'));
}
```

Then in the view you can

```
<h1>{{ $category->name }}</h1>

<p>======== Courses ========</p>

@foreach($category->courses as $course)
    <p>{{ $course->name }}</p>
    <p>Conducted By: {{ $course->teacher->name }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I guess the problem here is - $categories->courses is not working in this case. It's not returning anything. When it should.

```#relations: array:1 [▼
    "courses" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1422 ▼
      #items: []
      #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
    }
  ]```

Comment: @VenoM That's because you have wrong order of the keys in the relationship definition. You can either omit the keys as they are already as per convention or fix the order as per my updated answer.